# How to compare List<PeriodBase>s and get sorted Lists?

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have custom class `PeriodBase` which contains main properties for use:

```
 public class PeriodBase
 {

    TimeSpan? _endTime=null;
    TimeSpan? _beginTime=null;
    PeriodColor _periodColor=PeriodColor.Gray;

    public PeriodColor PeriodColor
    {
        get { return _periodColor; }
        set { _periodColor = value; }
    }

    public TimeSpan? BeginTime
    {
        get { return _beginTime; }
        set { _beginTime = value }
    }

    public TimeSpan? EndTime
    {
        get { return _endTime; }
        set { _endTime = value; }
    }
}

public enum PeriodColor
{

    Green,
    Red,
    Gray
}
```

and I have two `List<PeriodBase>` :

```
List<PeriodBase> refPeriods;
List<PeriodBase> donePeriods;
```

which i represent in this way (e.g):

[image: it is stock image]

But i want to represent it like this:

[image: this is what i want]

In other words, red parts must be in ref `List` , and green parts in done `List` and the other (gray) parts must be in both of `Lists` P.S work graphic presenter. How to make algorithm for comparing? As you see above i have enum for checking color of line. I need to refill the `Lists` in sorted form and separated. I know my explaining is very bad, because of that if you dont understand anything please tell me to explain again

Example(i will only show `TimeSpans`):

```
ref :  10:00-11:00 ; 13:00-18:00
done : 10:05-11:50 ; 14:00-17:50
```

after sorting

```
  ref : 10:00-10:05(red) ; 10:05-11:00(grey) ; 13:00-14:00(red) ; 14:00-17:50(grey) ; 17:50-18:00(red)
done : 10:05-11:00(grey) ; 11:00-11:50(green) ; 14:00-17:50(grey) ;
```

Comment: Is it List<TimeSpan> or List<PeriodBase> ?

Comment: Don't use `TimeSpan` to store points in time. Either use a `DateTime` to store the start time and a `TimeSpan` to indicate length of the period starting at that time or two `DateTime`s (start and end times). `TimeSpan` is for storing the _length_ of a given period.

Comment: oh sorry, i need to edit title. List is List<PeriodBase>

Comment: No. i need to keep both of Lists. But you can see pictures which i put above, red parts which "the period which user must be and it was not done  " and green parts "the period which user must not be , but it was done " and grey parts "the the period which user must be and it was done  " . i need to separate TimeSpans to get this

Comment: i added an example for what i want to

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do this in a few steps:

1. Convert your `List<TimeSpan>` to something like `List<Tuple<TimeSpan, bool>>` using LINQ
2. Union your two lists to one list
3. Sort your list by BeginTime
4. Iterate your list

   1. Check if there is a record starting >= your begintime and starting < your endtime: you have a "conflict". Determine color based on what's stored in the `Tuple<TimeSpan, bool>` where bool is a flag for ref/done
   2. Etc. (You just need to figure out when you need to color things etc. Some conditions basically)
5. Just add each and every PeriodBase to a list during the iteration

Answer (score 0):

I think your algortim should have a few steps:

1. Determine a list of overlapping periods per ref period.
2. Determine the list of free space per period by:

    a. determining the 0, 1, or 2 free periods per period + overlapping period combination.

    b. Intersecting all the free periods of all ref period together.

It might look like this:

```
var freePeriodsPerPeriod = 
    from period in refPeriods
    let overlappingPeriods =
        from donePeriod in donePeriods
        let periodsOverlap =
            period.EndTime > donePeriod.StartTime &&
            period.StartTime < donePeriod.EndTime
        where periodsOverlap
        select donePeriod
    select new { period, free = GetFreePeriods(period, overlappingPeriods).ToArray() };

IEnumerable<PeriodBase> GetFreePeriods(PeriodBase period,
    IEnumerable<PeriodBase> overlappingPeriods)
{
    return Intersect(
        from overlappingPeriod in overlappingPeriods
        from freePeriod in GetFreePeriods(period, overlappingPeriod)
        select freePeriod
    );
}

IEnumerable<PeriodBase> GetFreePeriods(PeriodBase period,
    PeriodBase overlappingPeriod)
{
    // return 0, 1, or 2 periods.
    yield return ...
    yield return ...
}

IEnumerable<PeriodBase> Intersect(IEnumerable<PeriodBase> periods)
{
    // TODO
}
```